# Giving more weight to a particular feature in scikit-learn decision trees

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-trees

I have a model that I train on same data, but i want a feature to have a stronger weight.

Say I have three features:

```
Car manufacturer's name
Price
Top speed
```

and I want to classify my cars as "Sport", "Luxury", "Family", "Compact" using these indicators. However, say that I realise the manufacturer's name is the strongest indicator, so I want that to weigh more. For example, if I buy a Ferrari, that is a sport car, even though the price tag may make it look like a luxury car. So, while I want to use all features, I want one of them to have a stronger weight (this is just a silly example, my actual problem is different, but this gives an idea). If a manufacturer makes all 4 kinds, speed and price are important, otherwise the name should have a stronger weight than the price and top speed. Basically, my tree should really look at the manufacturer's name and then split depending on the other features.

Can I set up sklearn in python to do this? How?

Comment: Not entirely sure but, I think you have to tune the min_weight_fraction_leaf parameter by providing some sample weights.

Comment: @RahulAedula Thank you, I tried to read the documentation, but I am quite confused, especially since it looks like you pass in it a single float value.

Answer (score 1):

You can create hierarchical models. The first model in the hierarchy would only get the single feature. The next model in the hierarchy would get the other features.

Scikit-learn does not support hierarchical modeling by default. You would have to write custom code.

Comment: +1, another way is to just put in redundant features (I always thought this would be a good extension to RF algorithms, input a set of weights/rules for the random feature selection).